Modeling of bass/ treble volume knob
I have a model
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6504273
of a bass/ treble volume knob which I need to resize and modify.
The hollow d-shaped section in the middle is the part which connects the knob to the rest of the amplifier.
This hollow section in the middle encompasses only about one half of the cylinder's height and I would like to make it go deeper into it.
In addition, I would like to resize the outer circumference of the cylinder, without changing the width of the hollow d-section.
Thank you for any help you can offer.

is it not the same question as your previous one?

To move down the inner bottom, choose Face Select Mode, switch to transparency (AltZ), select the bottom with the Lasso tool (CtrlRMB), select the Move tool and move down the selection:

For the outer diameter, disable the transparency, select the outer faces with the Lasso and SShiftZ:


Thanks, but when I use the lasso tool,not only the bottom but also parts of the walls are included in the selection. How can I select only the bottom?

You need to be precise, the lasso contour needs to include the faces you want, don't make the selection too large or it will select the other faces
